# Android - Set image over home screen?

Tags: android

I want to set image over home screen when my app runs, like crack screen applications(Ex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mk.g6.crackyourscreen&hl=en) to achieve something.

I beileve it has something to do with these permissions;
DISPLAY SYSTEM-LEVEL ALERTS
DISPLAY UNAUTHORIZED WINDOWS

But i cant find an example, tutorial or any article about it?

Thanks...

Comment: Can't you just display a totally transparent Activity?

Comment: Why not just make a transparent activity?

Comment: Well, the home screen should be still usable. it will be like a toast message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting a transparent activity. For that matter, you can make your activity use the Translucent theme, like this (put this in the Manifest):

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
```

([source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html))

Comment: Well, the home screen should be still usable. it will be like a toast message